# Unexpected Identifer when logging an array

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am sending over an array from node/express to my frontend.

like so:

```
res.render({product: req.product_data });
```

Now on the front end, I am purely testing to see if it is there and i do this:

```
<script>

 console.log(<%= product %>);

</script>
```

From here In the browser's console it say's `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Looks like so in the sources:

```
    console.log([object Object]);
```

I've tried to JSON.stringify it,

```
<script>

console.log(<%= JSON.stringify(product) %>);

</script>
```

Output:

```
console.log([{&#34;product_id&#34;:11089187470}]);
```

and when i do that I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: *"I've tried to JSON.stringify it"* - How? Please [edit] your question to show that code and its output.

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry about that, i updated it now.

Comment: if you are making request through ajax call, you can do 
res.send(JSON.stringify({product: req.product_data }));

Answer (score 0):

The `res.render` function is used server side by express to render template files (like jade/pug).

The JSON object containing variables you pass into the render function (typically as the 2nd argument, since the first argument specifies the template file you want to render) is for you to use in your **server side templates only**, it will not be available once the file is rendered and sent over to the client.